# Understanding _r from numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.zeros([4, 4])
b = np.ones([4, 4])
#vertical stacking(ROW WISE)
print(np.r_[a,b])

print(np.r_[[1,2,3],0,0,[4,5,6]])

# output is 
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

[1 2 3 0 0 4 5 6]
```

But here np._r doesn't perform vertical stacking, but does horizontal stacking. How does np._r work? Would be grateful for any help

Comment: Have you had a look at the official [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)?

Comment: Like all the `stack` functions, it does a `np.concatenate`, after tweaking the dimensions of the inputs.  The docs says it concatenates on `the first axis`.  In the first case the arrays are 2d; in the second 1d and scalar (0d).  `first axis` for a 1d array is the only axis, so the effect is the same as `hstack`.

Comment: To do vertical stacking `r_` would have to convert all the inputs to 2d.  That's what `vstack` does.  The `r_` docs show a `np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` that does that..  But the added 0's produce the same error as with `vstack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [324]: a = np.zeros([4, 4],int) 
     ...: b = np.ones([4, 4],int)                                                                                    
In [325]: np.r_[a,b]                                                                                                 
Out[325]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

This is a `row` stack; same as `vstack`.  And since the arrays are already 2d, `concatenate` is enough:

```
In [326]: np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)                                                                              
Out[326]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

With the mix of 1d and scalars, `r_` is the same as `hstack`:

```
In [327]: np.r_[[1,2,3],0,0,[4,5,6]]                                                                                 
Out[327]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6])
In [328]: np.hstack([[1,2,3],0,0,[4,5,6]])                                                                           
Out[328]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6])
In [329]: np.concatenate([[1,2,3],0,0,[4,5,6]],axis=0)                                                               
...
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

`concatenate` fails because of the scalars. The other methods first convert those to 1d arrays.

In both case, `r_` does

> Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.

`r_` is actually an instance of a special class, with its own `__getitem__` method, that allows us to use `[]` instead of `()`.  It also means it can take slices as inputs (which are actually rendered as `np.arange` or `np.linspace`).

`r_` takes an optional initial string argument, which if consisting of 3 numbers, can control the concatenate `axis`, and control how inputs are adjusted to matching dimensions.  See the docs for details, and `np.lib.index_tricks.py` file for more details.

In order of importance I think the concatenate functions are:

```
 np.concatenate    # base
 np.vstack         # easy join 1d arrays into 2d
 np.stack          # generalize np.array
 np.hstack         # saves specifying axis
 np.r_             
 np.c_
```

`r_` and `c_` can do neat things when mixing arrays of different shapes, but it all boils down to using `concatanate` correctly.